# Did Spain have 433.13K deaths in 2020 and 428.44K in 2019?

Tags: mortality, covid-19, spain

In a [related question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50201/did-spain-use-an-ice-rink-as-a-morgue) the OP linked to [this Knoema site](https://knoema.com/atlas/Spain/topics/Demographics/Mortality/Number-of-deaths) to show that Spain has had no excess deaths in 2020 from Covid-19:

[image]

I'm skeptical because the site doesn't cite any source for their info.

Furthermore, one can [easily find](https://countryeconomy.com/demography/mortality/spain) (alas also unsourced) "alternative facts" for mortality in Spain, which aren't monotonic in the previous years, e.g. countryeconomy.com:

[image]

Additionally EuroMOMO has this graph for *excess* deaths for Spain (alas in a big and ever-updated [page](https://www.euromomo.eu/graphs-and-maps))

[image]

There's no 2020 total I can easily get from EuroMOMO, but eyeballing it, it seems to me that integrating the large spike should be noticeable in contrast to previous years, i.e. the increase in 2020 vs 2019 should be more than 2019 vs 2018 etc.

Someone in comments pointed out to Spain's [own MOMO](https://momo.isciii.es/public/momo/dashboard/momo_dashboard.html), which no doubt is where from EuroMOMO gets their data, but I don't see an obvious total there for the year 2020 either. Spain's MOMO however does [offer the raw data in CSV](https://momo.isciii.es/public/momo/dashboard/momo_dashboard.html#datos). Adding the `defunciones_observadas` field (which seems to be the best as it has a date reporting correction) for `todos` (both sexes) for 2020, I get 4**65**,535, which is a higher number than Knoema reports (by approximately 32,400 deaths). Furthermore, if do the same exercise for 2019 (data is in the same CSV), I get 394,339 deaths for 2019, which is lower than either of the other sources (Knoema ~428K or countrydata ~417K) for that pre-pandemic year. I'm not 100% sure I'm adding the right field though.

So, **is that 433.13K (from Knoema) the true number of deaths in Spain in 2020?**
The same question goes for 2019: is
**428.44K the true number of deaths in Spain in 2019**?

The Knoema difference between these years is 4.69K, whereas Spain's MOMO (if I'm using the right field from their dataset and I did not mess up the addition(s)) results in a difference between 2020 and 2019 of some 71,196 deaths, an order of magnitude more than Knoema reports.

Comment: the big spike equals to about 40 excess deaths? Doesn't seem like a lot and would suggest that the 433k number could be right.

Comment: @user1721135: that's a [z-score](https://www.euromomo.eu/how-it-works/what-is-a-z-score). They don't give the raw numbers, as far as I can tell (at least not per country).

Comment: @user1721135: Europe-wide there [were](https://euromomo.eu/bulletins/2020-22) some 90K extra deaths at the peak of that spike, which hit some other countries (Italy, UK) almost simultaneously. I don't know how many exactly in Spain.

Comment: The Economist gives 69,702 excess deaths for Spain https://www.economist.com/graphic-detail/2020/07/15/tracking-covid-19-excess-deaths-across-countries

Comment: I think the official figures from EuroMOMO https://momo.isciii.es/public/momo/dashboard/momo_dashboard.html

Comment: Is the website that makes this claim notable?

Comment: Also, did you notice that the website seems to offer their source if you "sign up free"?

Comment: @mmmmmm: thanks, but I don't see a year total there. I have no doubt EuroMomo gets their data from the Spanish momo.

Comment: @Schmuddi: why don't you do that and post an answer then?

Comment: Because I'm not even convinced that the website (and hence, the claim) is notable. You, however, are skeptical about their claim and want to learn whether their number is valid… Just saying. A bit tongue in cheek: Would you accept an edit in which I change the line referring the lacking source to "I'm skeptical because they make their source only available after signing up, which I want others to do in order to answer my question"?

Comment: @Schmuddi: someone surely believed it; the guy who posted a q from it here and wrote the first comment under mine that it looks fine to him. All the 97 or so people who viewed his q and didn't DV (I was the only one insofar) probably sorta believed it.

Comment: One person believing this number doesn't establish notability at least in my book, nor does a lack of downvotes for a question that uses this number.

Comment: @Schmuddi: https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4702/what-does-it-take-to-prove-that-statement-on-a-data-website-is-notable

Comment: Today, January 18th, I would not be surprised if a reasonably legitimate site published data for 2020 based on estimates, not taking Covid into account at all.

Comment: At this point it is impossible to know how many deaths Spain had in 2020. It takes more than 18 days (today in January 18) to find and count all the bodies. There may be estimates out there, but it will take at least two more months until we have something resembling a final count. Counting deaths is much more complicated than what one might imagine.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [Taladris' comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50201/did-spain-use-an-ice-rink-as-a-morgue#comment233819_50201), the data source for Knoema's number is found on [another page](https://knoema.com/UNWPP2019/world-population-prospects-2019):

> The 2019 Revision of World Population Prospects is the twenty-sixth round of official United Nations population estimates and **projections** that have been prepared by the Population Division of the Department of Economic and Social Affairs of the United Nations Secretariat.
>
> LATEST UPDATE (3/26/2020)

So it seems these (433.13K deaths in 2020 and 428.44K in 2019) numbers are UN projections made in 2019.

I've tried to find the exact number in the [UN's files](https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Standard/Mortality/) and they turned out to be (both) estimated and interpolated. They have some kind of model that predicts/estimates them for groups of five years, e.g. for Spain I can find
[image] 1,985K for the 2010-2015 and 2,106K for 2015-2020 respectively. And then that data is [interpolated to annual data](https://population.un.org/wpp/Download/Standard/Interpolated/). In the screenshot below you can see Spain's interpolated numbers in the bottom right corner coinciding with the Knoema data

[image]

The (Excel) fields are formatted not to show decimals, but these are present in the UN data as 428.436 and 433.131 respectively for 2019 and 2020.

I'm not 100% sure of this since they marked everything as estimates in that file, but UN's own [data sources page for Spain](https://population.un.org/wpp/DataSources/724) says

> Spain
>
> Population: Total population and distribution by age and sex estimated to be consistent with the population by age and sex of the (a) 1950, 1960, 1970, 1981, 1991, 2001, 2011 censuses; (b) official estimates through 2017; and with estimates of the subsequent trends in fertility, mortality and international migration.
>
> [...]
>
> Overall Mortality: Life expectancy at birth and age pattern of mortality based on: (a) official estimates through 2014; (b) registered deaths by age and sex available through 2016; (c) International estimates used up to 2017.

It's a bit unclear if the total mortality is inferred from censuses or by adding the age group data. In any case, none of these UN figures is anything but an estimate for Spain starting with 2017.

Comment: Wow... so "Coronavirus didn't have an effect on mortality in Spain!  For proof, check out these projected mortality numbers from before they knew about coronavirus!"  Nice.

Answer (score 7):

The raw data are available from the Spain MOMO site at the "Datos" tab. The link labeled "aquí" [here](https://momo.isciii.es/public/momo/dashboard/momo_dashboard.html#datos) will give you a CSV file of deaths per date, either National or by region, starting 2018-12-31.

If I have done the calculations correctly, the current total for all-cause deaths in 2020 is **465,535**. I suggest the original question is based on incomplete data. (The CSV data will probably be revised, too, but not enough to change the big spike in deaths.)

Comment: There is a disturbingly common habit among covid skeptics to quote incomplete data as evidence covid mortality is low which suggests both motivated reasoning and severe data illiteracy at the same time.

Comment: Careful analysts understand the data and compile *consistent* time series for excess mortality. Like the [Financial Times](https://www.ft.com/content/a2901ce8-5eb7-4633-b89c-cbdf5b386938) (who have excess mortality in spain as >70k so far).

Comment: This doesn't add any substance that isn't already part of the question. Its more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @Caleb That's because this is a case of a question with its own answer in it.

Comment: @Caleb The question was edited to incorporate this answer (without credit).

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I thought of that, but the edits to the question were *before* this answer was posted.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus: That is actually an obvious untruth as the timestamps prove you've posted your answer (on Jan 19 at 2:30) **after** my last edit to the question (Jan 18 at 8:58)!

Comment: As I could not remember who pointed me to the Spanish MOMO data in the comments, I checked that now again. [It was](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/50202/did-spain-have-433-13k-deaths-in-2020-and-428-44k-in-2019/50212#comment233706_50202) user "mmmmmm", which as far as I can tell it's not the same person as you. And I've done my own calculations as Spanish MOMO didn't actually provide a total.